# jQuery Ajax: re-executing function on success, when function is NOT known beforehand

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm a WordPress theme developer (although its not WordPress specific question) and I've building an ajaxified theme having structure like this ...

```
<body>

        <div id="site-header"> content here </div>

        <div id="site-body"> content here </div>

        <div id="site-footer"> content here </div>

<body>
```

Now when any link is clicked, a jQuery script like this is executed ...

```
$.ajax({

      url: targetURL,
      dataType: "html",
      success: function(response) {

          var targetBody = $(response).filter('#site-body').html();

          $('body').prepend('<div id="ajax-body"></div>');
          $('#ajax-body').append(targetBody);

      }

 });
```

And it works perfectly fine. But now the issue is, target page may contain some elements e.g image slider, which uses some jquery plugin. Now when we will load the new page content in the #ajax-body div, image slider requires re-initiation of respective jquery plugin for proper behaviour ...

One solution is to call this function in Ajax callback function, it works. But this method only works when we know about the functions with certainty, and thus can include them manually in ajax callback.

Now, situation is such that final user can use any jquery plugin and i cannot call hundreds, if not thousands, of jquery plugins in ajax callback manually.

What could be the solution here?

Answer (score 0):

If you can break your parts into separate files, then you can use jQuery's `.load()` function.  If there's no selector expression, it will run any script blocks in the html.

http://api.jquery.com/load/

I ran into a similar requirement where `$.load()` didn't quite work the way I needed it, so I designed each 'template' page with it's own `function subPage_init()` that I would run after it was loaded by my ajax script.

I'm not a big fan of relying on convention, but sometimes it's the best option.

Comment: point here is, i do NOT know before hand of any function which needs to be re-executed. e.g in WordPress user can use any plugin and we cannot practically re-execute thousands of plugins functions manually in ajax callback or define any function in `subPage_init()`.

Comment: I guess I'm not seeing the big picture well enough...  Is it possible to set all your `$(document).ready()` code on the main page in a function, then call that function from both `$(document).ready()` and after the ajax load?

Comment: its not possible, code is not known, final user can plugin any set of code with existing site.